# Send request body сURL

Tags: json, windows, curl

I want to pass the request body, but it doesn’t work out for me, maybe I wrote it wrong

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "{"time": "2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000", "unread:" "true", "message": "hello","from":"Vadim"}" localhost:8080/api/save
```

Comment: Try this : ``curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8080/api/save -d '{"time": "2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000", "unread:" "true", "message": "hello","from":"Vadim"}'``

Comment: @baitmbarek Please don't post answers as comments

Comment: I have error bro

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I agree but it can't really be an answer, I can't test it :(

Comment: @baitmbarek post it as answer.

Comment: @damagedd Postman has a option to copy the request as curl command. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the json body or use single quote to wrap your json

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"time": "2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000", "unread:" "true", "message": "hello","from":"Vadim"}' 'localhost:8080/api/save'
```

Or on windows

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{'time': '2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000', 'unread': 'true', 'message': 'hello','from':'Vadim'}"
```

Comment: @damagedd did you try the single quote one? The escaping was indeed wrong

Comment: @damagedd If you are on windows switch the quotes `curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{'time': '2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000', 'unread': 'true', 'message': 'hello','from':'Vadim'}"`

Comment: I use cmd in windows

Comment: {"timestamp":"2019-12-30T10:03:32.608+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('t' (code 116)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character

Comment: can ypu open the chat?

Comment: The error you posted is an unexpected json. Maybe the boolean as string (just a hunch). But the curl request itself is working now

Answer (score 2):

You can get the crul command from the postman 
click on the code from drop down get the cURL which will give the cur command from that you can run

refrence link : https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

If you have swagger enabled for you Spring Boot APP from that also you can able to see crul command

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> -X POST "{"time": "2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000", "unread:" "true", "message": "hello","from":"Vadim"}"
> ```

Your JSON is invalid. `{"unread:" "true"}` should be `{"unread":"true"}`.

After that you need to escape the JSON's double quotes:

```
-d "{\"time\":\"2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000\",\"unread\":\"true\",\"message\":\"hello\",\"from\":\"Vadim\"}"
```

Obviously I can't test your `curl` command, but I think this should work for you.